# Move all files from a folder EXCEPT those still in use (by other processes like ffmpeg)

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, move

I am cleaning up a series of MP4 files using FFMPEG. I want to create a simple bat file script which moves the completed files (which are those which have a duration value), not the stubs of files in progress. This is the basic structure:

```
set SourcePath=C:\Source Folder
pushd %SourcePath%
move *.MP4 C:\Finished Folder
```

**What options are available** to use in the MOVE command to supress the moving of those files still in use by FFMPEG?

I did consider Robocopy's /minage or /minlad option for this, but the minimimum incremenent is DAYS, not seconds.

Comment: A file which is being used by another process can't be moved!

Comment: @double-beep - so, in effect, the solution I need occurs automatically?

Comment: Have you tried it? I am not so sure... Haven't tested.